# Sharepoint 2010. Can i store database information

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

Can i save some serialized objects to sharepoint 2010 database?

I need to save  List of SType objects:

```
class SType
{

string A{get;set;}
string B{get;set;}

}
```

And i dont want to create list for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at SPPersistedObject, it may fit your needs. (or may not, your question is not really specific)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.aspx
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1554-sppersistedobject-class-sharepoint-tutorial.aspx